# Giving multiple URL patterns to Servlet Filter

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, url-pattern

I am using a Servlet Filter in my JSF application.  I have three groups of Web pages in my application, and I want to check Authentication for these pages in my Servlet Filter:

my Folders

```
/Admin/ *.xhtml

/Supervisor/*.xhtml
/Employee/*.xhtml
```

and I am writing `web.xml` like

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ems.admin.servlet.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Employee/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Supervisor/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but requests like

```
http://localhost:8080/EMS2/faces/Html/Admin/Upload.xhtml
```

are not entering into Filter.

I have to provide security to these 3 folders.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If an URL pattern starts with `/`, then it's relative to the context root. The `/Admin/*` URL pattern would only match pages on `http://localhost:8080/EMS2/Admin/*` (assuming that `/EMS2` is the context path), but you have them actually on `http://localhost:8080/EMS2/faces/Html/Admin/*`, so your URL pattern never matches.

You need to prefix your URL patterns with `/faces/Html` as well like so:

```xml
<url-pattern>/faces/Html/Admin/*</url-pattern>
```

You can alternatively also just reconfigure your web project structure/configuration so that you can get rid of the `/faces/Html` path in the URLs so that you can just open the page by for example `http://localhost:8080/EMS2/Admin/Upload.xhtml`.

Your filter mapping syntax is all fine. However, a simpler way to specify multiple URL patterns is to just use only one `<filter-mapping>` with multiple `<url-pattern>` entries:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/Html/Employee/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/Html/Admin/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/Html/Supervisor/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: As far as I can see multiple url-pattern elements are not allowed and do not work as expected.

Comment: @SebastianG: Your concrete problem is caused elsewhere. Note that support for multiple `<url-pattern>` elements was introduced in Servlet 2.5 (part of Java EE 5, released almost 7 years ago). Perhaps you're working on a prehistoric beast, or you've severe configuration problems which causes that your container runs in a fallback modus matching Servlet 2.4 or older, hereby losing all Servlet 2.5 features.

Comment: Notice that multiple `<filter-mapping>` will execute the same filter twice if they match the same ressource, e.g one using `/*` and another one using `/foo.xhtml` as `url-pattern`. I encountered this behaviour on JBoss AS 7.1.

Comment: @Paranaix: That's indeed specified behavior. Perhaps you're mixing with servlet mappings which will indeed execute only the servlet with best matching URL pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868689/multiple-url-pattern-elements-in-web-xml

Answer (score 22):

In case you are using the annotation method for filter definition (as opposed to defining them in the `web.xml`), you can do so by just putting an array of mappings in the `@WebFilter` annotation:

```
/**
 * Filter implementation class LoginFilter
 */
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/faces/Html/Employee","/faces/Html/Admin", "/faces/Html/Supervisor"})
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    ...
```

And just as an FYI, this same thing works for servlets using the servlet annotation too:

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet({"/faces/Html/Employee", "/faces/Html/Admin", "/faces/Html/Supervisor"})
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ...
```

Comment: Isn't it better to extends a `Filter` instead of `HttpServlet` even if it is only an example?

Comment: A filter can be executed for different servlet URL patterns. You can not replace a filter with a servlet.

Comment: He wants a filter behavior, not a servlet one. I guess he has already mapped those URLs to servlets.