# *.faces and *.jsp mapping

Tags: jsp, jsf, url-pattern, servlet-mapping

in my project there is *.tiles for which I have mentioned the mapping for *.jsp in config.xml as shown below. Is it possible to do the same for *.faces?

```
    <definition name="/tiles/utilities/login.tiles" extends="base.definition">
        <put name="pageName" value="Login Page"/>
        <put name="body" value="/utilities/login.jsp"/>
    </definition>
```

I have tried to map *.faces and corresponding *.jsp by specifying in web.xml under  by mentioning the following url pattern:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>File Upload Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.file</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the filter-mapping in web.xml?

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FaceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>faces/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>FaceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.something.project.filter.FaceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

FaceFilter class:

```
...
import javax.servlet.Filter;
...

public class FaceFilter implements Filter{...
...
    @Override
    public void doFilter...
```

You can find more details here:
[Giving multiple URL patterns to Servlet Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645516/giving-multiple-url-patterns-to-servlet-filter)